# how can I exclude zero from an recursion python program following

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

```
def multipl_rec(l, n):
    if (n == 1) and (n!=0):
        multiple = l[0]
    else:
        multiple = multipl_rec(l,n-1) * l[n-1]
    return multiple
```

if I enter, I get

```
>>>l = [1,-2,5,0,-5]
>>>multipl_rec(l, len(l))
0
```

but I want to get 50 with the same values and for that I need to exclude 0

Comment: FWIW, `if (n == 1) and (n!=0)` is redundant. If `n == 1`, it pretty surely doesn’t equal 0.

Comment: so I need to but n==0? but it doent work

Comment: I tried butting a for loop to exclude zero

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what the program should do. We can guess but we shouldn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, this usage of `n` is somewhat confusing; its only job is to indicate the virtual end of the list, which would be easier replaced by simply truncating the list and omitting `n` as a separate parameter entirely:

```
def multipl_rec(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        multiple = l[0]
    else:
        multiple = multipl_rec(l[:-1]) * l[-1]
    return multiple
```

Next you can debate *how exactly* you'll want to omit `0` values; trying to skip over them in a recursive function can make things somewhat complicated, so instead let's just replace any `0` with `1`:

```
def multipl_rec(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        multiple = l[0] or 1
    else:
        multiple = multipl_rec(l[:-1]) * (l[-1] or 1)
    return multiple
```

And to make this less redundant, let's make the base case not `len(l) == 1`, but `len(l) == 0`:

```
def multipl_rec(l):
    if not l:
        return 1
    return multipl_rec(l[:-1]) * (l[-1] or 1)
```